# ASP.net bind expression

Tags: asp.net

I am looking into some code in a open source ASP.net web app - NopCommerce.
There is a binding expression in the tag that I never seen before.
Can someone tell me what it is?
How does this loginbutton get fired with out the "onclick" attribute?
Where can I find the source code class in the Solution?

Thanks

```
<asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" CommandName="Login" Text="<% $NopResources:Login.LoginButton %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is using ASP.Net Expressions, usually used for Connection Strings and implicit resource binding.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5bd1tad.aspx

They can be customized and extended.  In this case, the application (NopCommerce) has a custom resource builder:

http://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/t/2264/difference-between-getlocaleresourcestring-and-nopresources.aspx